# I tried 'npm run build' of firestore migrator code but nothing happens

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

This is probably a noob question. I want to use firestore migrator : 
https://github.com/codediodeio/firestore-migrator/issues
I followed the installation.

At the end when I type: 
`npm run build`
I got this :

> > firestoremigrate@0.3.0 build C:\Users\gogv\Desktop\firestore-migrator-master
> >
> > tsc

And then the terminal reload, nothing else happen and i'm no able to launch a fire-migrate command..  (command not found)

Could you let me know what I'm supposed to do ? 
Thank you in advance

Have a nice day

Comment: If you're having problems with someone's code from GitHub, then post an issue on that repo to let them know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let npm know where it lives. You can use `npm link`.